# Scraping the data past the view more button using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am scraping https://www.ndtv.com/topic/mumbai-crime but it only returns me the data of the first 15 articles. How would i go about extracting data from all the other articles?

The code which i am using is as follows:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
from datetime import datetime

def scrape_crime_data(location):
    url = f'https://www.ndtv.com/topic/{location}-crime'
    response = requests.get(url)

    if response.status_code != 200:
        print(f'Error {response.status_code}: Unable to fetch data.')
        return []


    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    crime_news = soup.find_all('li', class_='src_lst-li')

    if not crime_news:
        print(f'No crime news found for {location}.')
        return []

    crime_data = []

    for news in crime_news:
        title_element = news.find('div', class_='src_itm-ttl').find('a')
        title = title_element.text.strip()
        date_text = news.find('span', class_='src_itm-stx').text.strip()
        date_start = date_text.rfind('|') + 1
        date = date_text[date_start:].strip()
        description_element = news.find('div', class_='src_itm-desc')
        description = description_element.text.strip() if description_element else ''
        crime_data.append({'title': title, 'date': date,
                          'description': description})
    return crime_data
```

How can I extract the remaining data?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this example how to navigate the pagination on this particular site:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.ndtv.com/page/topic-load-more/from/allnews/type/news/page/{}/query/mumbai-crime"

for page in range(1, 5):  # <-- increase number of pages here
    u = url.format(page)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(u).content, "html.parser")

    for item in soup.select(".src_lst-rhs"):
        title = item.select_one(".src_itm-ttl").get_text(strip=True)
        text = item.select_one(".src_itm-txt").get_text(strip=True)
        print(title)
        print(text)
        print()
```

Prints:

```
...
Man Arrested For Dragging Motorcyclist Under Car Over 12 Km In Gujarat
More than a month after a man died from being dragged for nearly 12 kilometres pinned under a car post an accident, the vehicle's owner was held by Gujarat's Surat police on Thursday after being in hiding in Mumbai and Rajasthan, an official said.

2, Including 62-Year-Old Man, Arrested For Making Fake Passports In Mumbai
Two persons, including a 62-year-old man, were arrested by the Mumbai Crime Branch on Wednesday for allegedly making fake passports and visas and issuing bogus COVID-19 test reports, an official said.
```

Comment: this worked wonders, can you tell me how you constructed that url please? since i might have to do the same for scrapping more websites

Comment: @Samarth When you open Web developer tools -> Network Tab (in Firefox or Chrome) and click on More button, you will see the URL there

Comment: thanks a lot for this, this was really helpful